# Same exception type with different error message

Tags: java, exception

Ive two method that throw the same exception `throws IOException`

the problem is that each method throw it from different  reason, I wrap the methods
in the main with try catch, what is the recommended way to solve it ?
I need different message for each exception with the same type..

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

try{

….


readFile(path);

convert(file)

} catch (IOException e) {
    …..
}


private static String readFile(String path) throws IOException {
    //Here files requires IOException -  Reason here cannot Read file
    String lineSeparator = System.getProperty("line.separator");
    List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(path));
} 


private static String convert(String file) throws IOException {
   //Here reader requires also ioException- Reason here cannot parse file
    ObjectMapper reader = new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory());
    Object obj = reader.readValue(file, Object.class);

}
```

Comment: create your own exception then

Comment: Call the two methods in separate try/catch blocks.

Comment: or use the same block and check the error message through equals or contains to make sure which exception was thrown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several ways you could approach this.  One way, perhaps the heaviest in terms of new code you would need to write, would be throw a custom exception from each of your helper methods.  Then you could catch each specific exception in a separate block.

But what I might recommend here is that you simply wrap each of the two calls to your helper methods in separate `try-catch` blocks:

```
try {
    readFile(path);
} catch (IOException e) {
    // handle first exception here
}

// more code
try {
    convert(file)
} catch (IOException e) {
    // handle second exception here
}
```

This is fairly clean and doesn't require a lot of refactoring.  If you keep encountering this problem, then maybe consider creating custom exceptions for your application.  If you have a look at many Java libraries, you will see that they often use their own custom exceptions.

If you wanted to go the route of using a custom exception, you could define one, e.g.

```
public class FileReadIOException extends Exception {
    public FileReadIOException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

and then use it:

```
private static String readFile(String path) throws FileReadIOException {
    try {
        String lineSeparator = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(path));
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        throw new FileReadIOException(e.getMessage());
   }
}

try {
    readFile(path);
    // more code
    convert(file)
} catch (FileReadIOException e) {
    // handle first exception here
} catch (SomeOtherException e) {
    // handle second exception here
}
```

The above code showing custom exception is a bit contrived, because the reality is that all of your code is throwing `IOException`.  Creating custom exceptions in your case does not add much value, because they are already (rightfully) throwing an `IOException`.  I'm not sure that it doesn't make sense to handle just one type of exception.  More typically, if you were working on a large enterprise application, you would use custom exceptions to handle situations which go wrong in your own custom code.

Comment: Can you please give example for the first approach ?

Comment: also the problem is that I need to abort the program if one exception was raised ...

Comment: So the second approach is the recommended one ? I want to understand the best practice ...no the short solution

Comment: @RaynD It totally depends on the scope of what you are doing.  If you are writing a fairly small application, or just doing an assignment, I probably would just catch one `IOException`, or use two separate `try` blocks.  If you plan to build a large application, with its own unique behaviors and therefore errors, then creating custom exceptions starts to make more sense.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen In case of reading and writing files, there is not much of  a use for custom exception, they come into play once you actualy do something custom like parsing or comunication with third party. Creating new exceptions just to change the way stack is displayed, is the least productive thing, you can do.

Comment: @PanBrambor I totally agree, and maybe I did not make this clear when I gave that example, which was contrived and doesn't add a lot of value.

Comment: what with the abort , I need to abort the program for each execption that I got , should I use exit(1) in both exception (if I use the first proposal...)

Comment: You could consider using `System.exit()` to gracefully shutdown the program.  Or, you could structure your code so that the `main()`method just ends naturally in the case of an exception (without of course any other code running).

Comment: Tim regard  your second suggestion(in the comment) , this is what i've before in the post one try catch block which look clean code but cause to the problem that I've ...or maybe I missing someting ,`method just ends naturally in the case of an exception` can you please give example? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My way is usually to create your own exception and throw it like that

```
public class Snippet {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String path = "";
            readFile(path);
            String file = "";
            convert(file);
        } catch (MyException e) {
            // do whatever
        }
    }

    private static String readFile(String path) throws MyException {
        try {
            String lineSeparator = System.getProperty("line.separator");
            List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(path));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new MyException("Custom 'readFile' message", e);
        }
    }

    private static String convert(String file) throws MyException {
        try {
            ObjectMapper reader = new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory());
            Object obj = reader.readValue(file, Object.class);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new MyException("Custom 'convert' message", e);
        }
    }
}

class MyException extends Exception {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3166824380774329449L;

    public MyException(String message, Throwable cause) {
        super(message, cause);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
}
```

Tim's way is valid too.

Answer (score 0):

@OP The best person to solve this would be you yourself.
There are quite easily multiple ways to solve that. Check which one suits you more properly.

One of the solution as per me is below. This is based on the reason IOException is superclass to many other exceptions. [IOException documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/IOException.html)

```
try {
     readFile(path);
} catch ( FileNotFoundException e) {
     // handle first exception here
} catch ( EOFException e) {
     // handle 2nd exception here
}
```

For the above to work you would need to know which type of IOException is being thrown.

Another solution is check individual exception messages when you know what are expected messages you may receive.

```
try {
     readFile(path);
} catch ( IOException e) {
     if(e. getMessage().contains("TXT 1...") {
          //Case handle #1
     } else if(e. getMessage().contains("TXT 2...") {
          //Case handle #2
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to handle exception is not to have them. When exception is thrown, it indicates that natural lifecycle of your application has been interrupted for one reason or another. Most exceptions are self-explanatory and provide you with precise explanation of what happend, therefore creating new exceptions and re-mapping those thrown is almost always counterproductive and may result in more confusion than usefulness(especial if you work in a team).

Furthermore exceptions doesn't need to be terminal, in most cases, a scenario can be devised to retry/prompt different input etc. to ensure that lifecycle is not interrupted. Killing an application on exception can create more problems in some cases (e.g: not closing files properly, hence losing processed data).

Now to your actual problem. If you have two or more components, that throws unrelated exceptions(name is not a relation in this case), it is best not to have them in the same try/catch structure as less workaround will be necesary to scrap that one part, instead of the whole thing which can still exit on its own, or doesn't even need to be initiated.

Answer (score -1):

Here is my 5 cents

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    String path = "path";
    String path2 = "path2";


    try{
        readFile(path);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new Exception("read file exception", e);
    }

    try{
        convert(path2);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new Exception("convert exception", e);
    }


}


private static String readFile(String path) throws IOException {
    //Here files requires IOException -  Reason here cannot Read file
    String lineSeparator = System.getProperty("line.separator");
    List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(path));
}


private static String convert(String file) throws IOException {
    //Here reader requires also ioException- Reason here cannot parse file
    ObjectMapper reader = new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory());
    Object obj = reader.readValue(file, Object.class);
}
```